# Angular material virtural repeat ajax requests 2nd page altough there is no 2nd page

Tags: angular-material

I have an angular virtual repeater which works fine most of the time but sometimes, based on the item count I guess, it makes a secondary paging call to the server altough there are is no second page.

For example, my page size is set to 50. The ajax call returns 36 items, I update the internals like this:

```
 $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
     this.numItems = data.result.pagination.totalRecords;
     var items = data.result.departments; 
     ....// (I also tried changing the order of these lines)
     }).bind(this)
```

Then, the list gets displayed for a split second followed by a second ajax call to the next page. Which returns nothing and due to my server side code the pagination is also 0 which eventually deletes the existing data.

Now, I could modify the server side to return the row count even if an out of bound page number is requested but I'd rather like to troubleshoot the issue of firing a second ajax pagination call, when there is clearly no more data to display.

This isssue apears about half the time when there is only one page. I mean, I keep clicking a button that refreshes the list and sometimes it shows OK and sometimes not.

I am using 1.1.1/angular-material, the repeater is in a full height flex div.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `this.numItems` is bound to your callback `function (data){});` and not the parent function. Try to declare something like `var self = this`:

```
var self = this;
$http.get(url).success(function (data) {
 self.numItems = data.result.pagination.totalRecords;
 var items = data.result.departments;
```

you still may need to add some logic to check the `numItems` somewhere outside.

Comment: thats not the case, I use {{departments.numItems}} to show the result count and it displays correctly.  I edited the code in my original post, adding:   "}).bind(this) "to the end, I think thats the part that binds the self to the parent object, which is "departments".  Somehow, the repeater is not satisfied by the first response and thinks there may be further records on the next page. I have currently aleviated the situation by playing with the css height for the container and items and the issue has vanished. But dev is ongoing so I know it will come back : )  I'll keep this thread posted

Comment: You are calling `bind` on a wrong method. Basically you bind your function to what is returned from success. So you either have to declare callback outside and bind it or use self approach. Would help if you would post bigger snippet of the code